# C Programming: Reading from a file and printing on screen - formatting

Tags: c, struct, structure

I am trying to read from a file test.txt and display it on screen. 
This is what I have in my test.txt file:

```
22,100,22,44.44,0,Jon Snow
32,208,42,55.94,0,You know nothing
23,54,103,36.96,0,Winter is coming
```

I have tried this code and everything seems to be working except that I am getting an extra "," when I print on my screen. This is what gets printed on screen:

```
 1| 22| ,Jon Snow             | 44.44| 100 |   22 |
 2| 32| ,You know nothing     | 55.94| 208 |   42 |
 3| 23| ,Winter is coming     | 36.96|  54 |  103 |
```

I am really hitting a brick wall here. Not sure where this extra "," is printed. How do I get rid of "," above? 
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Item {
   double value;
   int unit;
   int isTx;
   int quant;
   int minquant;
   char name[21];
};
struct Item MI[4];
int NoR = 3;

void display(struct Item item, int nline);
void list(const struct Item item[], int Ntems);
int load(struct Item* item, char Name[], int* PtR);
void InvSys(void);
int menu(void);

int main(void)
{
    InvSys();
    list(MI, NoR);
    return 0;
}
void display(struct Item item, int nline)
{
    if (nline == 0)
    {
        printf("|%3d| %-21s |%6.2lf| %3d | %4d | \n", item.unit, item.name, item.value,  item.quant, item.minquant);
    }
    else
    {
        //something
    }
}

void list(const struct Item item[], int Ntems)
{
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < Ntems; k++)
    {
        printf("%6d", k + 1);
        display(item[k], 0);
    }
}

int loadItem(struct Item* item, FILE* Dfile)
{
    int ret = fscanf(Dfile, "%d,%d,%d,%lf,%d", &item->unit, &item->quant, &item->minquant, &item->value, &item->isTx);
    if (ret != 5) {
        return -1;
    }
    fgets(item->name, sizeof item->name, Dfile);
    item->name[strlen(item->name)-1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}


void InvSys(void)
{
    int variable;
    load(MI, "test.txt", &variable);
}


int load(struct Item* item, char Name[], int* PtR)
{

    *PtR = 0;
    int ret;
    FILE* varr;
    varr =  fopen(Name, "r");
    while (varr)
    {
        ret = loadItem(&item[*PtR], varr);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ++*PtR;
        }
        }
fclose(varr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). There are a few tips in there that would make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
fscanf(Dfile, "%d,%d,%d,%lf,%d", &item->unit, &item->quant, &item->minquant,
       &item->value, &item->isTx);
```

scans 5 numbers and 4 comma characters, leaving ",Name" in the input buffer. That's where the leading comma comes from.

Change it to:

```
fscanf(Dfile, "%d,%d,%d,%lf,%d,", &item->unit, ...
```

and your extra comma should disappear.